# Laravel 5.6: Redirecting after registration form

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project that requires me to redirect to login after registering not to the home screen. I have tried to use a $redirectTo in the RegisterController but it seems to be ignored and control is handed over to the home page. How can i rectify this

```
protected $redirectTo = '/login';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Laravel generates the session after registration, so you need to put the given below code in RegisterController.

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('message', 'Your message');
}
```